# In my process stats, Why is the bar partly blue?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings

I'm using a Sony Xperia Z3 compact, on Android 4.4.4.

I know that in the [process stats](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2014/01/process-stats-understanding-how-your.html) in developer mode, the bar shows the proportion of time the device is in low/medium/high memory usage. Shown by green, yellow and red respectively.

However, my process stats bar looks like this:

[image]

Why is the left side blue?

Comment: May I know what device model is this? If I remember correctly, the icon on Nexus (KitKat) should be a gear shown on the linked blog. Meanwhile, on my Lollipop, I see dark green and dark grey bar.

Comment: I'm using a Sony Xperia Z3 compact. Sony seems to have put in their own UI, though I doubt the functionality is affected.

Comment: I agree that the functionality is not affected, but since the color displayed is different than other devices, and I couldn't find any reference, probably the "best" solution is to call Sony directly. Even I can't understand the meaning of the color for Lollipop 5.0 on Nexus 4 since it's different that the blog mentions.